# How to expose a Custom Web service class in Salesforce Sites?

Tags: apex, webservices, force.com-sites, soap

I'm trying to make a simple sample exposing a web service class in Salesforce sites, so basically I already:

1. Developed a webService class

   global class QuickBooksWS {

   ```
   webservice String userName { get; set; }
   webservice String password { get; set; }

   public QuickBooksWS() {
       this.userName = 'value';
       this.password = 'password';
   }

   webservice static String authenticate(String userName,String password){
       return 'looged in as :'+userName +'and password: '+password;
   }
   ```

   }
2. In my salesforce site I give access to the QuickBooksWS class and then, when I want to access to:

https://demo1fieldirect-developer-edition.na50.force.com/services/Soap/class/QuickBooksWS

I'm getting the next page:

[image]

I expect to see the WSDL definition in this part so I can just play with SOAP UI for example

Is anything wrong with my code / configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn't work that way (which, admittedly, is different than most other systems that support WSDL/Web Services). To get the WSDL for a class, you need to call `/services/wsdl/class/ns/ClassName`, where `ns` is the namespace for the class, if any (do not include if not in a named package), and `ClassName` is the class' name.